# selenium python can't click on each item in dropdown list

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I need to click every item in dropdown list from this [page](https://www.zzounds.com/item--PGHPHM) and I write this code for click every items in dropdown list but I am getting error  `element is not attached to the page document` after click on few items.

here is my code:

```
option_variations = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#sid')
if option_variations:
    options = [x for x in option_variations.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")]
    for i in options:
        variation = i.text
        click_item = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//*[contains(text(), '{variation}')]")
        click_item.click()
        print(f"sucessfully click on item {variation}")
        time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Clicking the option refreshes the page so all your elements are stale. Perhaps you could put the entire code block in a loop that keeps track of which option it is supposed to click + the max # of options.

Comment: selenium gives references to objects in browser memory. But when you click element then memory in browser is changing and it can't find previous objects. After `click` you would have to search again options and use `options[index+1]` to click next option.

Comment: click on `#sid` then click on the option `#sid > option:nth-child(?)`

Comment: @furas it would be better if you can give an example using my code. I am new in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should work:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service())

# open page
driver.get("https://www.zzounds.com/item--PGHPHM")

# get the variations into an array
elements = driver.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="#sid option")
values = []
for element in elements:
    value = element.get_attribute("value")
    values.append(value)
print(values)

# click on each variation
for value in values:
    click_item = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=f"#sid option[value='{value}']")
    click_item.click()
    print(f"sucessfully click on item {value}")
    time.sleep(1)
```

The problem what the xpath selector itself for each variant was not always valid and you must start by creating a simple list of strings for each option.